# How to display the value in textbox using php session?

Tags: php

I am just learning php and I need to set the value of a session to the html textbox. I wrote the php code inside value attribute of the input but it displaying the entire code instead of the variable stored in the session. Please guide me.

```
<input type="text" name="usernametxt" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["user"]; ?> "/>
```

Comment: You seem to have wrong web server setup - php seems disabled... Can you post setup details: web-server, installed modules, OS, etc? - alternatively see [php_info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Comment: Im using Xammp, win 8.1...I have other php function in other page which works fine. Only displaying variable in textbox is not working. It shows the php code i wrote in the textbox

Comment: @batwing : are you running above code in `.php` file ?

Comment: Can confirm the filename is `.php` and not `.html`?

Comment: Sorry, yes the filename was html. I have changed it  to php. Now working finely. Sorry again.